# Django Schedule and queue Non periodic Tasks

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, celery, django-celery

I am looking for Job Task Scheduler in Django. I have looked into django-celery, but all the documentation shows is the periodic scheduling of task. But what I am looking for is to add a task to queue and schedule it at a specific time, till that time the task can go to sleep. Also, it has to be executed only once. Is my conclusion about django-celery correct? Is there a better way or any other way to schedule non-periodic tasks.

Comment: [`django-cron`](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, celery is a good tool for the task, the [documentation](https://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/executing.html#eta-and-countdown) states exactly what you need, specifically just specify an eta when apply_async a task:

```
from celery import task
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

@task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

tomorrow = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
add.apply_async(args=[10, 10], eta=tomorrow)
```

Comment: I guess I didn't read the documentation carefully enough. Thanks anyways.